# Linked list - insert

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I am trying to insert elements of a file in a linked list, I used two functions, one that loads and which inserts, the function loads is running, apparently, in the correct way, however the function insert is initiating the implementation and does not end, testing i noticed that she manages to enter the first 3 lines of the file, but does not complete correctly the insertion, as the code is long, it follows, that part of it problems:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define RECS_PATIO 2

struct Rec_Emp {
    char nome_rec[10];
    int uso_rec;
    int taxa_rec;
/*    struct Rec_Emp *prox; */
};

typedef struct Rec_Emp recuperadora;

struct Patio {
    char iden_patio;
    int capacidade;
    struct Patio *prox;
    struct Rec_Emp *lista[RECS_PATIO];
}; 

typedef struct Patio patio;

void insere_patio (patio *cabeca, patio *novo) {
    patio *p = cabeca; 

    while (p->prox != NULL)
        p = p->prox; 
    novo->prox = p->prox; 
    p->prox = novo;

}

void carrega_patio (patio *pa, patio p, recuperadora r1, recuperadora r2) {
    patio *pt = pa;
    FILE *f; 

    f = fopen ("portorec.txt", "rt");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf ("Problema na abertura do arquivo");
        return;
    }

    while (!feof(f)) {
        fscanf (f, "%d %c %s %s %d %d %d %d", &p.capacidade, &p.iden_patio, r1.nome_rec, r2.nome_rec, &r1.uso_rec, &r2.uso_rec, &r1.taxa_rec, &r2.taxa_rec);

        p.lista[0] = &r1;
        p.lista[1] = &r2;
        insere_patio(pt, &p);   

    }
    fclose(f);
}

int main {

patio *PT;
    PT = malloc(sizeof(patio));
    PT->prox = NULL; 
    patio pat;
    recuperadora rec1, rec2;    
    carrega_patio(PT, pat, rec1, rec2);
}
```

File

```
600000 A REC01 - 0 -1 6000 -1
600000 B REC01 REC03 0 0 6000 8000
600000 C REC02 REC03 0 0 6000 8000
600000 D REC02 - 0 -1 6000 -1
2400000 E ER01 ER02 0 0 8000 8000
2400000 F REC04 ER01 0 0 8000 8000
2400000 G REC04 - 0 -1 8000 -1
2400000 H REC05 - 0 -1 8000 -1
2400000 I REC05 - 0 -1 8000 -1
2400000 J  ER02 - 0 -1 8000 -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main`, you declare `patio pat` as an automatic variable (allocated on the stack). Automatic variables are not initialized by default, so you are getting whatever random garbage happens to be on the stack as the value for `pat.prox`. I expect your list insert is chasing random garbage pointers throughout memory, looking for `p->prox == NULL`.

In addition, you are not dynamically allocating your memory in `carrega_patio`. The parameters `patio p, recuperadora r1, recuperadora r2` are all structures, but those structures are going to be *reused* every time through your loop.

Imagine filling out a paper form with 1 line of this data. And then starting from the top of the same paper form and filling out the exact same form with a different line of this data. And then again, and again.

Because you are not separately allocating memory, you can't create a list. You need to call `malloc()` or `calloc()` to allocate a "new piece of paper" for each record.

Try something like this (note: not tested):
    #include 
    #include

```
typedef const char * FILESPEC;

typedef struct rec_emp {
    #define RE_NOME_DIM 10

    int      re_taxa;
    int      re_uso;
    char     re_nome[RE_NOME_DIM];
} REC_EMP;

typedef struct patio {
    #define PA_LISTA_DIM 2

    struct patio *pa_prox;
    int     pa_capacidade;
    char    pa_iden;
    REC_EMP pa_lista[PA_LISTA_DIM];   /* NOTE: structs, NOT pointers */

    #define pare(pa,n) ((pa)->pa_lista[(n)])
} PATIO;

PATIO *
patio_novinho()
{
    PATIO * p = calloc(1, sizeof (PATIO));
    return p;
}

void
patio_insere(cabeca, novo)
    PATIO * cabeca;
    PATIO * novo;
{
    while (cabeca->pa_prox) {
        cabeca = cabeca->pa_prox;
    }
    novo->pa_prox = cabeca->pa_prox;
    cabeca->pa_prox = novo;
}

void
patio_carrega(cabeca, arquivo)
    PATIO * cabeca;
    FILESPEC arquivo;
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(arquivo, "rt");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("patio_carrega: Problema na abertura do arquivo");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (!feof(fp) && !ferror(fp)) {

        PATIO * pa = patio_novinho();

        fscanf(fp, "%d %c %s %s %d %d %d %d",
            &pa->pa_capacidade,
            &pa->pa_iden,
            pare(pa,0).re_nome,
            pare(pa,1).re_nome,
            &(pare(pa,0).re_uso),
            &(pare(pa,1).re_uso),
            &(pare(pa,0).re_taxa),
            &(pare(pa,1).re_taxa)
        );

        patio_insere(cabeca, pa);

    }

    fclose(fp);
}

int
main()
{
    PATIO * cabeca = patio_novinho();
    patio_carrega(cabeca, "portorec.txt");

    /* more stuff here */
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: On insert, you are generally required to pass the *address of* the list as a parameter because when the memory is allocated for the node and assigned as the head (the address of the list), you must act on the actual pointer itself and not a copy. That is why, at a minimum, the insert must check two conditions, (1) whether this is the first node in the list; and (2) if not iterate to next free node to insert.

Comment: I think the OP is working around that by always using a 'dummy' node at the front of the list. Trading heap for code, as it were.

Comment: Yes, that is why the 'generally' was used, but using a dummy node to mask the assignment often leaves out an important part of the learning necessary to fully understanding manipulating the first node in a list. That's why I dropped it as a comment without more.

Comment: Wow, honestly i am not on the level in c to think a solution such as this. Some things that you used i don't even know it was possible to do so, this solution made me read to have a good understanding of the terms. Ran well, the insertion and the other part of the code is running right now, the terms of the program are coordinated. I owe you a pint. Thanks